# vue v-show отображение массива

Tags: vue.js

Не могу понять почему не работает v-show.

Запросом получаю массив пользователей:

```
0: {IDUSER: "63", NAME: "Иванов Иван Иванович", NUMBER: "141", HIDE: "0"}
1: {IDUSER: "0", NAME: "Администратор", NUMBER: "118", HIDE: "0"}
2: {IDUSER: "64", NAME: "Иванов Иван Иванович", NUMBER: "143", HIDE: "0"}
3: {IDUSER: "30", NAME: "Иванов Иван Иванович", NUMBER: "0", HIDE: "1"}
4: {IDUSER: "7", NAME: "Иванов Иван Иванович", NUMBER: "0", HIDE: "1"}
```

Отображаю след.образом:

```
<template v-for="user in users">
  <input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxInputName" :value="user.IDUSER" :id="user.IDUSER" v-model="checkedUsers" />
  <label class="list-group-item" :for="user.IDUSER" v-show="user.HIDE">
    <span>{{ user.NAME }}</span>
    <span class="float-right text-muted">{{ user.NUMBER }}</span>
  </label>
</template>
```

Хотелось-бы по умолчанию не отображать пользователей с Hide = 1,  а сделать через toogle switch (показывать скрытых пользователей да/нет). Но даже обычный v-show не отрабатывает как положено. 
С Уважением, Waik/

Comment: `v-show="!user.HIDE"`

Comment: "user.HIDE" - показывает вообще всех.
"!user.HIDE" - не показывает вообще никого.
@РустамГимранов поправил теги

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-show` должно получать логическое значение `0,1,true или false`. В вашем коде все значения `HIDE` являются строками, что вызывает некорректную обработку состояния.

Привожу пример работы вашего кода (с исправлениями):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    checkedUsersAll:false,
    checkedUsers:[],
    users : [
    {IDUSER: "63", NAME: "Иванов Иван Иванович", NUMBER: "141", HIDE: 0},
    {IDUSER: "0", NAME: "Администратор", NUMBER: "118", HIDE: 0},
    {IDUSER: "64", NAME: "Иванов Иван Иванович", NUMBER: "143", HIDE: 0},
    {IDUSER: "30", NAME: "Иванов Иван Иванович", NUMBER: "0", HIDE: 1},
    {IDUSER: "7", NAME: "Иванов Иван Иванович", NUMBER: "0", HIDE: 1}
  ]
  }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">

  <input type="checkbox" id="CheckBoxInputNameAll" name="CheckBoxInputNameAll" v-model="checkedUsersAll" /> 
  <label for="CheckBoxInputNameAll">Показать всех</label>
  <hr>
<template v-for="user in users">
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxInputName" :value="user.IDUSER" :id="user.IDUSER" v-model="checkedUsers"  v-show="!user.HIDE || checkedUsersAll"/>
  <label class="list-group-item" :for="user.IDUSER" v-show="!user.HIDE || checkedUsersAll">
    <span>{{ user.NAME }}</span>
    <span class="float-right text-muted">{{ user.NUMBER }}</span><br/>
  </label>
</template>
{{checkedUsers}}
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо. Не обратил внимания что hide у меня string а не int.